# Memory leak in Linux, but not Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, python-requests

I have a script I am making where it will receive domains from a third party web socket, import them into a queue and then send HTTP requests to the domains to find out if they are reachable or not. However, because I am receiving domains from the web socket at such a high rate, I am trying to implement threading into the script to have multiple threads sending the HTTP requests to keep up with the rate I am receiving them at. However, when I run the script on my Linux box, I get a memory leak issue which does not exist on my Windows box, and I ideally would like this to run on my Linux box.

So far I have tried making sure that my Linux box is on the same or higher version of Python (3.8.3), and trying multiple HTTP modules (Requests, urllib3 and HTTP Client) but they all exhibit the same issue. I hope someone is able to help as I have tried to resolve this myself for the past couple weeks, but not been able to come up with anything, the affected code is this:

```
import http.client
import threading
from queue import Queue

enclosure_queue = Queue(maxsize=500)

# Thread that adds the domains acquired from the web socket into the queue 

def scan_domain(q):
    while True:
        domain = q.get()
        try:
            conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(domain)
            conn.request("GET", "/")
            r1 = conn.getresponse()
            response = r1.read()
            conn.close()
            domain = "http://" + domain
            result = response.decode()
            print("Connected to - " + domain)
            q.task_done()
        except:
            print("Unable to connect to - " + domain)
            q.task_done()

for i in range(30):
    t = threading.Thread(target=scan_domain, args=(enclosure_queue,))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```

I have left out the thread that adds the domains to the queue because it may contain sensitive information, however, I am using that exact portion of code in a different script that doesn't show this issue so that part is 100% not part of the issue.

Comment: did you find any root cause?